# How to set an image for an inactive button

Tags: android

I want to set a specific image when my button is not clickable. This button image is already selected according focused and pressed state thanks to this xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:clickable="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cmb_bouton_acces_inactive" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cmb_bouton_acces_hover" />

    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/cmb_bouton_acces_hover" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cmb_bouton_acces" />

</selector>
```

But I do not know how to define a new image for the button when it is not clickable.

Any idea ?

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 2):

Try `android:state_enabled="false"` as the qualifier. [Here is a link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f8467edf7f714a80/ef6014f46c35a824?#ef6014f46c35a824) to a thread that shows an example.